# Multiple column search criteria GridView

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datagridview, sqldatasource

I'm trying to perform a search using multiple criteria specified by TextBoxes and DropDownList.
The issue I'm facing is that I require a way to attach additional `AND LIKE` commands if said TextBoxes/DropDownList have values in them, unfortunately the button doesn't behave the way I want it to, it shows no data on the grid. Even with the blank TextBoxes, the button doesn't perform the `SELECT` command.

CODE BEHIND:

```
protected void queryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Filter = "";

    if (resIDSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + "ID LIKE '%" + resIDSearch.Text + "%' AND "; }
    if (DFirstName.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + "FirstName LIKE '%" + DFirstName.Text + "%' AND "; }
    if (DLastName.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + "LastName LIKE '%" + DLastName.Text + "%' AND "; }
    if (contactNumSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + "ContactNumber LIKE '%" + contactNumSearch.Text + "%' AND "; }
    if (lotNumSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + "LotNumber LIKE '%" + lotNumSearch.Text + "%' AND "; }
    if (streetSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + "StreetName LIKE '%" + streetSearch.Text + "%' AND "; }
    if (villiageSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + "VilliageName LIKE '%" + villiageSearch.Text + "%' AND "; }
    if (vTypeBox.SelectedIndex != 0) { Filter = Filter + "VehicleType LIKE '%" + vTypeBox.SelectedItem.Text + "%' AND "; }
    if (statusBox.SelectedIndex != 0) { Filter = Filter + "StatusID LIKE '%" + statusBox.SelectedValue + "%' AND "; }
    if (DriIDSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + "UserID LIKE '%" + DriIDSearch.Text + "%' AND "; }
    if (resDateSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + "ReservationDate LIKE '%" + resDateSearch.Text + "%' AND "; }
    if (destSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + "Destination LIKE '%" + destSearch.Text + "%' AND "; }
    if (pickUpSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + "PickupLocation LIKE '%" + pickUpSearch.Text + "%' AND "; }

    if (Filter.Length > 0)
    {
        string FinalFilter = Filter.Remove(Filter.Length - 4, 3);
        resDataSource.FilterExpression = FinalFilter;
    }
    else {
        reservationTable.DataBind();
    }
}
```

.NET SCRIPT:

```
<asp:GridView OnRowDataBound="reservationTable_RowDataBound" DataSourceID="resDataSource" CssClass="table table-bordered dataTable text-center" Width="100%" ID="reservationTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="Reservation ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="Driver ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="Driver First Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Driver Last Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StatusID" HeaderText="Status" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactNumber" HeaderText="Customer Contact #" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LotNumber" HeaderText="Lot Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StreetName" HeaderText="Street Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VilliageName" HeaderText="Villiage" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Note" HeaderText="Additional Information" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VehicleType" HeaderText="Vehicle Requested" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReservationDate" HeaderText="Reservation Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Destination" HeaderText="Destination" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PickupLocation" HeaderText="Pick up" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="resDataSource"
    runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteDatabase%>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteDatabase.providerName%>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM Reservation"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Can you check how your final filter looks like. Is that query return some value from your DB?

Comment: Finalfilter removes the AND part of the query string. Filter is initialized as "" so it has a length of 0. If any of the textboxes are not empty, filter's length is changed, triggering Finalfilter.

Answer (score 0):

Aspx:
                                    
                                        
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                            
                                        
                                    
                                    "
                                        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteDatabase.providerName%>"
                                        SelectCommand="select * from Reservation">

```
        string Filter = "";
        string command = "SELECT * FROM Reservation WHERE";

        if (resIDSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + " ID LIKE '%" + resIDSearch.Text + "%' AND"; }
        if (DFirstName.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + " FirstName LIKE '%" + DFirstName.Text + "%' AND"; }
        if (DLastName.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + " LastName LIKE '%" + DLastName.Text + "%' AND"; }
        if (contactNumSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + " ContactNumber LIKE '%" + contactNumSearch.Text + "%' AND"; }
        if (lotNumSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + " LotNumber LIKE '%" + lotNumSearch.Text + "%' AND"; }
        if (streetSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + " StreetName LIKE '%" + streetSearch.Text + "%' AND"; }
        if (villiageSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + " VilliageName LIKE '%" + villiageSearch.Text + "%' AND"; }
        if (vTypeBox.SelectedIndex != 0) { Filter = Filter + " VehicleType LIKE '%" + vTypeBox.SelectedItem.Text + "%' AND"; }
        if (statusBox.SelectedIndex != 0) { Filter = Filter + " StatusID LIKE '%" + statusBox.SelectedValue + "%' AND"; }
        if (DriIDSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + " UserID LIKE '%" + DriIDSearch.Text + "%' AND"; }
        if (resDateSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + " ReservationDate LIKE '%" + resDateSearch.Text + "%' AND"; }
        if (destSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + " Destination LIKE '%" + destSearch.Text + "%' AND"; }
        if (pickUpSearch.Text != "") { Filter = Filter + " PickupLocation LIKE '%" + pickUpSearch.Text + "%' AND"; }

        if (Filter.Length > 0)
        {
            reservationTable.DataSource = resDataSource;
            string FinalFilter = Filter.Remove(Filter.Length - 3);
            resDataSource.SelectCommand = command + FinalFilter;
            reservationTable.DataBind();

        }
        else {
            reservationTable.DataBind();
        }
```

I actually Solved it by altering the sqldatasource Select command in the code behind, some concats and it was working great! Follow each text spacing just as I have it.